# Why Repository interface bind to service container

Tags: laravel, repository

We need to use Repository in **laravel** application. We want create Two important things one is Repository Interface and another one Repository class

**My doubt** is Why Repository interface and Repository class register to service provider

I removed **repository interface and class** from service provider

show below error

"**Target [App\Repository\UserInterface] is not instantiable while building** "

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository\user;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class UserRepoServiceProvide extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

    }


    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
       // $this->app->bind('App\Repository\UserInterface', 'App\Repository\user\UserRepository');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Interface` class is just a definition of methods (without their body), hence is not instantiable. That means you can't do a `new App\Repository\UserInterface()`.

Somewhere in your code you have a method (or maybe a constructor?) that takes a `UserInterface` dependency, something like

```
public function myMethod(UserInterface $repository) {
    ...
}
// or
public function __construct(UserInterface $repository) {
    ...
}
```

If you remove the binding, Laravel will try to instantiate an `UserInterface` and that will result in the error you get.
When working with interfaces you have always to `bind()` them with concrete classes.

I have a question, why did you remove the binding from ServiceProvider?

Comment: Hi Leonardo,

Thanks for reply 

You ask one question "why did you remove the binding from ServiceProvider?"

Because why we register UserInterface to serviceprovider (like this $this->app->bind('App\Repository\UserInterface', 'App\Repository\user\UserRepository');) 

we directly inject the interface to controller 

for example suppose we want user model methods we not register user model in service provider instead we directly inject user model in controller and access them.
Then why Repository is register into service provider

Comment: You can't inject directly an interface. Laravel's service container must know how to resolve that interface, that's why you need the binding in your service provider.